# Red Hat cannot boot after clone with dd

Tags: linux, boot, ext3, dd

I used `dd` to clone a x4100 server with Linux Red Hat. The hardware is identical for old and new servers. Disks are `sda`, `sdb` and `sdc`(`sdc1` and `sdc2`). But newly restored server gives following errors and Linux can only be started in maintenance mode (read-only):

```
Red Hat nash version is starting:
shpchp: shpc_init: cannot reserve MMIO region.
shpchp: shpc_init: cannot reserve MMIO region.
shpchp: shpc_init: cannot reserve MMIO region.
shpchp: shpc_init: cannot reserve MMIO region.
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while
(...)
/boot: ext3 recovery flag is clear but journal has data.
/boot: Run journal anyway    
/boot: Unexpected inconsistency RUN fsck manually.
```

What might be the reason? Did I miss something during backup/restore? How can I fix the new system?

Comment: Can you provide the `dd` commands you used to both copy the original disk and transfer it to the new one?

Comment: dd if=/dev/sdc | gzip | ssh root@backupserver dd of=/root/sdc.gz (backup)                                      
                                                                   dd if=sdc.gz | ssh root@newserver "gunzip -c | dd of=/dev/sdc"
(restore)
I used to RIP cd to set up ssh connection on the new server.

Comment: A stupid question: have you executed the backup command running the system from a live CD, or anyway with all `sdc` partitions unmounted?

Comment: I unmounted the partitions manually but not tried to use live cd? might there be a problem during unmount? Should I use also RIP or knopix to run backup?

Comment: Have you tried running `fsck` manually? Something like `fsck -C -y /boot`

Comment: fsck did not work first but I changed the options according to your suggestion, now it is OK but I have problems in Oracle. thank you very much!

Comment: ssh for piping dd? Interesting. I normally use netcat for this.

Comment: Can you check if there was an external journal used on the original system?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't `dd` the drive while it was *mounted* did you?  If you're doing to use this mechanism for duplicating a disk, boot into a rescue OS (e.g. from a CD or USB drive) so that you unmount your FS before copying it.

Or, in a pinch, you can cheat by using the magic sysrq to remount all drives readonly, but that has consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are able to boot from the grub into single user mode? Try Linux rescue mode and see if you can fsck all the partitions.

Also, please try updating the initrd file, since the hardware is changed. Goto single user mode/rescue mode from grub and in shell, mount the root filesystem and execute the following

```
# cp /boot/initrd-2.6.16-1.2129_FC5.img /boot/initrd-2.6.16-1.2129_FC5.img-original
# mkinitrd -fv --preload=ehci-hcd --preload=usb-storage --preload=scsi_mod --preload=sd_mod /boot/initrd-2.6.16-1.2129_FC5.img 2.6.16-1.2129_FC5
```

Also update the grub configuration file (menu.lst or grub.conf) and make sure the correct file is referenced in the boot stanzas.

Comment: It has been noticed that in some versions of mkinitrd, the iscsi related drivers are not updated to detect multipath io scsi configuration, though. So, download and install the correct/updated version of mkinitrd compatible with the kernel version and run the command, incase the existing mkintrd does not resolve the case. I was trolling through some of the links  and found this errata on RHN http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2009-0237.html, if it helps.